# AMQP-CPP RabbitMQ receiving extra sign, message.body() by one greater than message.size()

Tags: c++, rabbitmq, amqp

When I receive a message, I get the message content with message.body(), but always with an extra character at the end. The content of message.body() is always one greater than message.size(). The extra character is'Î' and has the ASCII code Decimal 206, I don't understand why this character is included. I always have to cut off the message around this sign, which need not be.

My Callback for receiving messages:

```
void Communicator_RabbitMQ::MessageCB(const AMQP::Message &message, uint64_t deliveryTag, bool redelivered)
{
    cout << "Message received: (" << message.body() << ") , " <<  "Body Size: " << message.bodySize() << endl;

}
```

Example:

Published the following payload via the RabbitMQ Management UI: : "12345"

Output from Callback:

```
Message received: (12345�) , Body Size: 5
```

Debugger:

```
*(message.body() + 5)   0xce 'Î'    const char
```

When I consum the message with the RabbitMQ Management UI, I receive the following Payload :

Payload
5 bytes *12345*
Encoding: string

Comment: It's an error in your code. Without sharing your code, it's impossible to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider that

```
message.body()
```

returns a pointer to a NOT-null-terminated string. You should use message.bodySize() to check the actual length.

***Example 1: (copy content)***

```
void Communicator_RabbitMQ::MessageCB(const AMQP::Message &message, uint64_t deliveryTag, bool redelivered)
{
    cout << "Message received: (" << std::string(message.body(), message.body() + message.bodySize()) << ") , " << "Body Size: " << message.bodySize() << endl;
}
```

***Example 2: (using c++17's string_view)***

```
void Communicator_RabbitMQ::MessageCB(const AMQP::Message &message, uint64_t deliveryTag, bool redelivered)
{
    cout << "Message received: (" << std::string_view(message.body(), message.bodySize()) << ") , " << "Body Size: " << message.bodySize() << endl;
}
```